# FileMaker Terminal command

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I want to run a Terminal command from within FileMaker. I use the Perform AppleScript script step with a native AppleScript:

```
do shell script "rsync -r Documents/Monturen/ fakeuser@fakeserverhosting.be:www/"
```

I installed a SSH Key on the remote server. The goal is to automate the sync of images.

I do get a 23 error. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, in Terminal it works

Answer (score 0):

This is rsinc error 23 - some files could not be transferred. Try to transfer one file with explicitly defined full file path.

I think there is a problem with the source filepath as well. Shouldn't this be

```
~/Documents/Monturen
```

or

```
~/Documents/Monturen/*
```

If you have any spaces in your file names or folder names they have to be escaped with \\. The same applies to any apostrophes.